# Round minutes 20 in 20 in visual fox pro

Tags: visual-foxpro

please i'm having problems resolving a function about a program in Visual Fox Pro.

I need to make a rounding down every 20 minutes in decimal.
For example: if i recive 19 minutes (0.316) y need return 0 minutes.
if i get between 0-19 minutes, return 0 minutes
if i get between 20-39 minutes, return 20 minutes
if i get between 40-59 minutes, return 40 minutes
if i get between 60-79 minutes, return 60 minutes

i was thinking use ROUND() but i don't know how because "Round" Approaches to the nearest decimal.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Am using this, but if want round 500 minutes...?
IIF(VAR1>0,IIF(BETWEEN(VAR1,0,0.3166),0,IIF(BETWEEN(VAR1),0.3333,0.8166),0.3333,0)),0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
roundedMinutes = Floor( m.myMinute / 20 ) * 20
```

For example:

```
Create Cursor SampleMin (minutes i, rounded i)
Local ix
For ix = 1 To 600
    Insert Into SampleMin ;
        (minutes, rounded) ;
        values ;
        (m.ix, Floor(m.ix/20) * 20)
Endfor

Locate
Browse
```

Comment: Your answer works perfectly, thank so much.
very simple

Answer (score 1):

Here's a small prg I made that will hopefully help you or at least start you in the right direction.

```
lnStart             = 0
lnEnd               = 20
lnReceivedMinutes   = 500
llNotDone           = .T.

IF lnReceivedMinutes > 0
    DO WHILE llNotDone
        IF BETWEEN(lnReceivedMinutes, lnStart, lnEnd)
            llNotDone = .F.
            MESSAGEBOX(ALLTRIM(STR(lnStart)) + " Minutes")
        ELSE
            lnStart = lnStart + 20
            lnEnd = lnEnd + 20
        ENDIF
    ENDDO
ENDIF
```

I check to see if the value received is between my `lnStart` and `lnEnd`. If it is not then I check for the next 20 minutes.

Comment: Thank you so much! Work it perfect

Answer (score 1):

Cetin Basoz gave correct answer

```
roundedMinutes = Floor( m.myMinute / 20 ) * 20
```

I have checked myself